# How to create a dropdown list with a constant and validate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a drop down from the constant `NOTIFY`.

In the view:

```
<%= f.select(:notify, NOTIFY) %>
```

In environment.rb because I use the constant in different classes:

```
NOTIFY = [['Never', 'never'],['Immediately', 'immediately'],['End Of The Day', 'end_of_day']]
```

In my model I want to validate that what is stored is part of the list:

```
validates :notify, allow_blank: true, :inclusion => { :in => NOTIFY }
```

The lower case key (second value in the array) is sent as a parameter and therefore I get the validation error.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
validates :notify, allow_blank: true, :inclusion => { :in => NOTIFY.map{ |n| n.last } }
```

inclusion expects an array to check for the included list for validation. And, that's what you're missing.